In Azure Application Insights how do I unmask client IP address
I noticed all the exception loggings in the 'Failures' come client Ip zeroed.  How do I turn this one or unmask so the client IP is visible on every logging?

Can you provide the code that you have tried

You can do with ITelemetryInitializer in Program.cs and get the client Ip in custom dimensions too, If you want I can provide an answer with that.

You need to disable IP-masking. Though it is not possible to through Azure Portal directly you can do it using ARM templates, PowerShell, etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection?tabs=framework%2Cnodejs

Thanks @ZakiMa for inputs, I do agree and I followed the same Microsoft-Document and as an alternative(if you do not have permissions to use Powershell or ARM and change the settings)  way use telemetry with code:
RithIpTest.cs:
public class RithIpTest : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry ri_tel)
    {
        ISupportProperties ri_pt = ri_tel as ISupportProperties;

        if (ri_pt != null && !ri_pt.Properties.ContainsKey("client-ip"))
        {
            string ri_cl = ri_tel.Context.Location.Ip;
            ri_pt.Properties.Add("client-ip", ri_cl);
        }
    }
}

In program.cs added:
var rb = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
rb.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
rb.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(rb.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"]);
rb.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, RithIpTest>();
------
------
app.Run();

With the above code, in customdimensions you will able to get the client ip .
Output:
When Client is running:

When run from  local:

This will work for traces , failures, requests, etc.

How would you do this in client-side Javascript?

Read this doc, in this it is clearly mentioned.

@RithwikBojja, I think this is the scenario where service side submits telemetry on behalf of its client. Client itself doesn't know its IP address.

Have you checked Client-side JavaScript
